# How can I filter a react-table based on the condition that the row is selected

Tags: react-table

I have a button in my table component which when clicked I'd like to apply a filter on the data to look at the rows and if the isSelected property is true then display only those rows. I have a custom filter which I attach to the ID column ...

```
const selectedRowFilter = (rows, ids, filterValue) => {
    if(filterValue) {
      return rows.filter((row) => {
        return row.isSelected;
      });
    }
    return rows;
  };

const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'ID',
        accessor: 'id',
        filter: 'selectedRowFilter',
      }, etc...
```

I then call the filter programatically on click of a button using setFilter ...

```
setFilter('id', true);
```

The issue I have is when the table is reloaded when I edit the data for example the filter is re applied but the row.isSelected values are at this point undefined. Any help appreciated. This could be an issue due to the useRowSelected plugin having to be after the useFilters plugin.

https://codesandbox.io/s/new-breeze-uzhv8